# Unexpected behavior with nested Oracle SELECT query

Tags: oracle

Would love to get some help here understanding an unexpected behavior with an Oracle SELECT query. And maybe there is a nicer way to construct my query.
Basically, this is the query that gets me the distinct set of IDs that I'm after:

```
select distinct(c.LOCATIONID) from COURSESESSION c where c.MARKETID=280 and c.STATUSID in(1, 2)
        and c.COURSESESSIONID not in (SELECT distinct(REGISTRATION.COURSESESSIONID) FROM REGISTRATION)
```

But I also want all the data for these distinct IDs form COURSESESSION table, so I'm wrapping the above query in yet another select statement, so it looks like this:

```
select * from COURSESESSION cs where cs.COURSESESSIONID in 
    (select distinct(c.LOCATIONID) from COURSESESSION c where c.MARKETID=280 and c.STATUSID in(1, 2)
        and c.COURSESESSIONID not in (SELECT distinct(REGISTRATION.COURSESESSIONID) FROM REGISTRATION));
```

The first query returns a set of 21 records, but the second set returns 19, so I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this right. The triple-select query is basically for these 2 steps:

```
Set idsSet = select distinct(c.LOCATIONID) from COURSESESSION c where c.MARKETID=280 and c.STATUSID in(1, 2)
        and c.COURSESESSIONID not in (SELECT distinct(REGISTRATION.COURSESESSIONID) FROM REGISTRATION)

select * from COURSESESSION cs where cs.COURSESESSIONID in(idsSet);
```

Anyone knows how to fix my triple-select query?

Comment: Are you sure LOCATIONID and COURSESSIONID are supposed to match? That sounds unlikely; but it's what your `in` is looking for? Any hits you are getting now might just be coincindental.

Comment: I did compare data from both queries, it is 98% the same, but I get your point @AlexPoole. I just want to get the data for the distinct ids that get selected in the first query. But maybe I need to have them to be separate statements?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. You want all data for all courses in COURSESESSION which are in any of the locations found by your first query - even the ones that have other market ID or statuses (so `cs.LOCATIONID in ...`)? Or all data for all the courses that give you those locations (so without the extra level of subquery)? Adding table structures sample data and expected results to your question would help.

Comment: The outer query selects the data from a different table. Apart from semantically strange query, you may move `in` subquery to the ` right join` and find identifiers that are missing

Comment: @astentx - I'm using 2 tables and 3 select statements. The COURSESESSION table is the table from which I'd like to read the data filtered by distinct ids from the same table. The second table is the REGISTRATION, used for filtering of COURSESESSION ids only.

Comment: But `COURSESESSIONID` is not `LOCATIONID`

Comment: I got it - i was reading the data from the wrong table in my tripple-select, this works: 
select * from LOCATION l where l.LOCATIONID in 
(select distinct c.LOCATIONID from COURSESESSION c where c.MARKETID=280 and c.STATUSID in(1, 2)
        and c.COURSESESSIONID not in (SELECT distinct(REGISTRATION.COURSESESSIONID) FROM ERAPP.REGISTRATION));